# Why am I getting 'Unable to connect to the server: context deadline exceeded' error when creating GKE job?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-shell

am trying to create a GKE job by following the instructions in the official documentation.

I am doing it though via Cloud Shell. I have created the yaml file, however when I run the command:

kubectl apply -f config.yaml

I am getting the following error:

Unable to connect to the server: context deadline exceeded

What is the problem and what exactly is a context deadline?

I have made sure to enable the GKE API.

I wondered whether I needed to create a cluster first before submitting the job, but the tutorial makes no mention of creating a cluster.

Comment: Yes you need to create a cluster and you need to use this [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) to have access to the control plane (will create the kubeconfig file that kubectl tool needs to reach the endpoint). Curious which tutorial you are implementing ?

Comment: thanks @Fady it was from the gke documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs

Comment: You might have missed it, but it was stated in the [Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-workloads-overview) of the documentation ¨These controller objects represent the applications, daemons, and batch jobs running on your clusters.¨